# Value of the given expression ...

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

If $$y=\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}\right)$$ then value of $(2x+14y)^3-343$ is ?
I reduced the equation as $y=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}\right)$ but I couldn't simplify it further. Thanks!

Comment: Use $1+\cos x=2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}$ and $1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos x=\dfrac{1-\tan^2\dfrac x2}{1+\tan^2\dfrac x2}\iff\tan^2\dfrac x2=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}$$

WLOG $0\le x\le\pi$

$$\implies\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}=\cot\dfrac x2=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac x2\right)$$

$$\implies\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}=\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac x2$$

Comment: But how to find the value ?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, So we have $$2y+x=\pi$$  Should be question be $$(2x+4y)^3-343=?$$

Comment: No it's exactly like what I have written so I am struggling in spite of your answer

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, What's the source of the problem?

Comment: An app providing problems to practise for competitive exams. No option given with the problem is negative so I am not getting the answer

Comment: Also the correct answer is $9865$

Answer (score 1):

You can use a half-angle identity; specifically, $\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos(x)}{1 - \cos(x)}} = \cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right).$ So we have that $y = \tan^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$. This is simply equal to $\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{x}{2},$ so $2y = \pi - x$ and $x = \pi - 2y.$

Performing the substitution (no numerical answer can possibly be solved for), we have the expression is equal to $\boxed{(2\pi + 10y)^{3} - 343}.$

Comment: But all options are numerical?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure how that can be. With the equation $x = \pi - 2y,$ there isn't a substitution that will make $2x + 14y$ a number...

Answer (score 1):

Recall the bisection formulas:
$$
\left|\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}},
\qquad
\left|\cos\frac{x}{2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}
$$
so you have
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}}=\left|\cot\frac{x}{2}\right|
$$
For $x\in(0,\pi)$ we have $\cot(x/2)>0$, so
$$
y=\arctan\cot\frac{x}{2}
$$
and therefore $\tan y=\cot(x/2)=\tan(\pi/2-x/2)$ and therefore $y=\pi/2-x/2$.

For $x\in(\pi,2\pi)$ we have $\cot(x/2)<0$, so
$$
y=-\arctan\cot\frac{x}{2}
$$
and $\tan y=-\cot\frac{x}{2}=-\tan(\pi/2-x/2)=\tan(x/2-\pi/2)$, so
$$
y=x/2-\pi/2
$$

In the case $x\in(0,\pi)$, we have $2x+14y=7\pi-5x$; in the case $x\in(\pi,2\pi)$ we have $2x+14y=9x-7\pi$.

The case $x=\pi$ is very easy: $y=0$.

It's more complicated if $x$ is supposed to be an arbitrary real number (excluding numbers of the form $2k\pi$, for $k$ an integer).

---

If the answer has to be $9865$, you need either
$$
7\pi-5x=\sqrt[3]{10208},\qquad 0<x<\pi
$$
or
$$
9x-7\pi=\sqrt[3]{10208},\qquad \pi<x<2\pi
$$
The first case gives an acceptable solution $x\approx 0.05969$. The second case gives an acceptable solution $x\approx 4.85376$.